Next.js cannot save cookies in the browser sent from Express.js backend - In Production
I'm encountering an issue where cookies set by an Express.js backend are not being saved in the browser when accessed through a Next.js frontend. This behavior is consistent across all browsers tested (Chrome and Firefox) production environments. However, I've observed that the cookies are successfully received and stored in the browser during development but fail to work in the same way once deployed to production.
Here's a more detailed overview of my setup and findings:
Backend (Express.js):

Setting the cookie: When a specific endpoint is hit, the server responds with a Set-Cookie header containing the necessary cookie data.

   const token = generateToken(user._id);
    // user.password = undefined
    const filterUser = await User.findOne({ email }).select(
      "-password -role -_id -createdAt -updatedAt -__v -socialMedia"
    );

    //set cookie
    res.cookie("token", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true,
      sameSite: "None",
      partitioned: true,
    });


Testing the cookie directly: If I access this endpoint directly via Postman or a similar tool, the cookie is correctly received and stored.

Direct testing in development: Similarly, when accessing the endpoint directly in the development environment, the cookie is correctly received and stored.


Frontend (Next.js):

Fetching the cookie: Requests to the Express backend are made using Axios within the Next.js app. Upon inspection in the Network tab of Chrome DevTools, the Set-Cookie header is present in the response, but the cookie does not appear in the Application tab under Cookies in both development and production environments.

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS): CORS has been configured on the Express side to accept requests from the Next.js origin, including credentials. The configuration remains unchanged between development and production.


// cors setup
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: `${processEnv.ORIGIN_URL}`,
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);

Client-side fetching: When making requests, credentials: 'include' is specified. This approach is consistent between development and production environments.
// Create an Axios instance
const apiClient = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: API_ENDPOINT,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
});

Despite the cookies being received and stored in development, they are not behaving as expected in production. This discrepancy leads me to believe there might be an environmental difference affecting the cookie handling process.
Could anyone shed light on potential causes for this issue, especially considering the difference in behavior between development and production environments? Are there specific configurations or considerations unique to production deployments that could affect cookie handling?

If you are delpoying your project on a PaaS as Heroku.
You must add app.set('trust proxy', 1);
in your express code.
PaaS's are likely using load balancers that act as a proxy between client and server.

I initially tried using Render, but when that didn't work, I switched to Vercel, which also wasn't successful. Now, I want to give Heroku a try as well.
